# create folder in azure logic apps for azure file storage

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Is there a way to create a folder, in logic apps, for Azure File Storage?

I see "Create file" but that's about it. Other connector have "Create Folder" actions, but not Azure File Storage.

Answer (score 1):

thanks! I came up with a workaround, maybe it helps someone. 
I used "Create File" action, and in the path, I added the folder I needed. Logic apps creates missing folders in the path: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently Logic App does not support to create folder in storage file share.

If you want to improve it, you can post your idea in the azure [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps).